# New Relic Logging is not working nest js monorep

Tags: logging, nestjs, newrelic, monorepo

I'm integrating New Relic into my Nest.js monorepo application for monitoring. I've successfully set up the New Relic agent, and it's tracking the application's traffic. However, I'm facing an issue with log forwarding to New Relic.

I'm using Nest-Pino for logging in my Nest.js application. Although the logs are generated and visible in the console, they are not being forwarded to New Relic for centralized logging.

Here's my New Relic agent configuration in `newrelic.js`:

```js
'use strict';

exports.config = {
  app_name: [process.env.NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME],
  license_key: process.env.NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY,
  distributed_tracing: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  logging: {
    level: 'trace',
  },
  application_logging: {
    enabled: true,
    forwarding: {
      enabled: true,
      max_samples_stored: 10000,
    },
  },
  allow_all_headers: true,
  attributes: {
    exclude: [
      'request.headers.cookie',
      'request.headers.authorization',
      'request.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'request.headers.setCookie*',
      'request.headers.x*',
      'response.headers.cookie',
      'response.headers.authorization',
      'response.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'response.headers.setCookie*',
      'response.headers.x*',
    ],
  },
};
```

Here's an example of my environment variables in `.env`:

```
NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=flash_trade
NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=
NEW_RELIC_NO_CONFIG_FILE=true
NEW_RELIC_APPLICATION_LOGGING_FORWARDING_ENABLED=true
```

here is my folder structure
[folder strucer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ECxv.png)

I expect the logs to appear in the New Relic dashboard for centralized logging, but they are not showing up. I've verified that the Nest-Pino logging integration is working correctly, as I can see the logs in the console.

Any guidance on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a matter of realizing how to get the actual data in specific categories. I suggest you click on the log lines themselves.

For example, if you click on JSON logs, you can see the JSON metadata being available and that you could click in the upper right on the + button and add the keys for any areas that you want to see.